# Using vector types to improve OpenCL kernel performance

Tags: opencl, gpu

I have the following OpenCL kernel, which copies values from one buffer to another, optionally inverting the value (the 'invert' arg can be 1 or -1):-

```
__kernel void extraction(__global const short* src_buff, __global short* dest_buff, const int record_len, const int invert)
{                                                                                                           
    int i = get_global_id(0); // Index of record in buffer                                              
    int j = get_global_id(1); // Index of value in record                                                       

    dest_buff[(i* record_len) + j] = src_buff[(i * record_len) + j] * invert;
}
```

The source buffer contains one or more "records", each containing *N* (`record_len`) short values. All records in the buffer are of equal length, and record_len is always a multiple of 32.

The global size is 2D (number of records in the buffer, record length), and I chose this as it seemed to make best use of the GPU parallel processing, with each thread being responsible for copying just one value in one record in the buffer.

(The local work size is set to NULL by the way, allowing OpenCL to determine the value itself).

After reading about vectors recently, I was wondering if I could use these to improve on the performance? I understand the concept of vectors but I'm not sure how to use them in practice, partly due to lack of good examples.

I'm sure the kernel's performance is pretty reasonable already, so this is mainly out of curiosity to see what difference it would make using vectors (or other more suitable approaches).

At the risk of being a bit naive here, could I simply change the two buffer arg types to `short16`, and change the second value in the 2-D global size from "record length" to "record length / 16"? Would this result in each kernel thread copying a block of 16 short values between the buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your naive assumption is basically correct, though you may want to add a hint to the compiler that this kernel is optimized for the vector type ([Section 6.7.2 of spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.0.pdf#page=154)), in your case, you would add

> **attribute**((vec_type_hint(short16)))

above your kernel function. So in your example, you would have

```
__attribute__((vec_type_hint(short16)))
__kernel void extraction(__global const short16* src_buff, __global short16* dest_buff, const int record_len, const int invert)
    {                                                                                                           
        int i = get_global_id(0); // Index of record in buffer                                              
        int j = get_global_id(1); // Index of value in record                                                       

        dest_buff[(i* record_len) + j] = src_buff[(i * record_len) + j] * invert;
    }
```

You are correct in that your 2nd global dimension should be divided by 16, and your record_len should also be divided by 16. Also, if you were to specify the local size instead of giving it NULL, you would also want to divide that by 16.

There are some other things to consider though.
You might think choosing the largest vector size should provide the best performance, especially with such a simple kernel. But in my experience, that rarely is the most optimal size. You may try asking [clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) for CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_SHORT, but for me this rarely is accurate (also, it may give you 1, meaning the compiler will try auto-vectorization or the device doesn't have vector hardware). It is best to try different vector sizes and see which is fastest.

If your device supports auto-vectorization, and you want to give it a go, it may help to remove your record_len parameter and replace it with [get_global_size(1)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/get_global_size.html) so the compiler/driver can take care of dividing record_len by whatever vector size it picks. I would recommend doing this anyway, assuming record_len is equal to the global size you gave that dimension.

Also, you gave NULL to the local size argument so that the implementation picks a size automatically. It is guaranteed to pick a size that works, but it will not necessarily pick the most optimal size.

Lastly, for general OpenCL optimizations, you may want to take a look at the [NVIDIA OpenCL Best Practices Guide](https://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/CUDABrowser/downloads/papers/NVIDIA_OpenCL_BestPracticesGuide.pdf) for NVidia hardware, or the [AMD APP SDK OpenCL User Guide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide2.pdf) for AMD GPU hardware. The NVidia one is from 2009, and I'm not sure how much their hardware has changed since. Notice though that it actually says:

> The CUDA architecture is a scalar architecture. Therefore, there is no performance
>   benefit from using vector types and instructions. These should only be used for
>   convenience.

Older AMD hardware (pre-GCN) benefited from using vector types, but AMD suggests not using them on GCN devices (see [mogu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519746/using-vector-types-to-improve-opencl-kernel-performance/58529616#comment103432870_58529616)). Also if you are targeting a CPU, [it will use AVX hardware if available](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iocl-opg-using-vector-data-types).

Comment: "AMD hardware though, does use vector hardware." << that's actually wrong. The old AMD architectures (pre-GCN) benefited from vectors. GCN (all their GPUs since 2012) is different. See their guide [here:](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm_Documentation/blob/master/Programming_Guides/Opencl-optimization.rst)

`2.9 Specific Guidelines for GCN family GPUs: `

* Vectorization is no longer needed, nor desirable; in fact, it can affect performance because it requires a greater number of VGPRs for storage. I is recommended not to combine work-items.

Comment: @mogu I guess my newfangled HD-6970 isn't as modern as it used to be. Thanks for the correction. I'm glad that's the case, as it always bugged me that there was no efficient way to perform loads from __local memory where each vector lane has a different address.